# Style identification: Low-poly or what

Tags: style-identification

I've seen this art style over multiple websites in the past, but just can't seem to identify an underlying style/category for it. It seems to be some geometry based low-poly, but searches don't really match it. Is it maybe a subset of low-poly?

A couple examples:

[image]
[image]

[Source](https://www.16personalities.com/)

Comment: After seeing [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/117357/63979) I'm wondering why they only used white people...

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a kind of evolution of characters illustration. Adding the word *"character"* at the end of each of the following styles, Google shows several results.

- Pixel Art Characters
- Isometric Pixel Art Characters
- Block Isometric Characters
- Isometric Low Poly Characters
- Low Poly Characters
- 3D Low Poly Characters

---

*[Vectorstock](https://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/set-of-pixel-art-style-characters-vector-20263846)*

[image: pixel art]

---

*[CreativeMarket](https://creativemarket.com/lemonoff/859464-Vector-isometric-character)*

[image: Isometric]

---

[*Freepick*](https://www.freepik.com/premium-vector/block-isometric-cartoon-character-vector-art-graphic_2060850.htm)

[image: Block Isometric]

---

[*Shutterstock*](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/isometric-business-people-group-human-resources-573983179?src=agoZp-bI-Uq0STyKdschMw-1-1)

[image: Isometric low Poly]

---

*[ShutterStock](https://www.shutterstock.com/de/image-vector/superhero-actions-icon-set-low-poly-482522692?src=zT9W6H3GL6Pd2BffEUV7Eg-1-3)*

[image: Low Poly]

---

[Behance](https://www.behance.net/gallery/44657667/3D-Low-Poly-Characters)

[image: 3D Low Poly]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would say that it is in fact low poly art, though it's a cleaner and more contemporary look than traditional low poly art.

I'm sure it has a particular name, can't find it at the moment.

Compare it with other low poly images: ([Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=low+poly+art&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK2oS2kuPeAhXNmuAKHdJYBzEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1597&bih=792))

[image]
[image]

Comment: This tomato and elephant seem to be in a rather different style to the examples in the question. Your examples are definitely 3D, whereas the ones in the question are a sort of hybrid 2D-3D -- for example their heads are definitely 3D but their limbs are just 2D.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's what I was trying to point out, Danielillo's answer summed it up excellently.

Comment: FWIW "Low poly papercraft" is what I'd call it, and the result I get from Google image search appear to agree.

Answer (score 3):

It is *flat shaded* low-poly: each polygon is a single, solid color.